# Dispatcher Servlet mapping error in spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I need to run this project in spring 3 alone. I cannot use spring boot or any other technology stack.

I have tried to write a simple hello world application but I am getting a 404 error.

My files are like below.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.hpe" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.hpe;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sayHello() {
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to access localhost:8080/{context-name}/hello I get a 404 error.

Comment: On which server  your are deploying? What is your context-path?

Comment: I am deploying on tomcat 7 server. My context-path is "HPAssignment"

Comment: tomcat configured in eclipse? or standalone?

Comment: configured in eclipse

Comment: <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.hpe" /> your base package is  right

Comment: yes it is. The package is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You try this simple and tell to me it is working yaa not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: @SpringLearner - Can you please tell me where is the mistake in the code.

Comment: @Rammohan do you tiles?

Comment: please give me your all  project hierarchy detail where you can put pojo class,jsp file,controller etc...

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestMapping("/")` class level annotation on `HelloWorldController`.

Comment: Is your contextPath correct? This is what you set in `eclipse -> tomcat -> modules -> Path`  .  Also what is  the full error that your are getting?

Comment: and also make sure your `hello.jsp` is in `WEB-INF/jsp` folder

Comment: I am having hello.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp folder

Comment: OK. Try this url - `localhost:8080/HPAssignment/{yourWarFileName}/hello`

Comment: That's weird! Did you try to deploy the app to  standalone tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct to me. Try

1) verifying your context root ->http://localhost:8090/%nameofwar
%/hello

2) check if war is getting built correctly. Check if all the required artifacts like web.xml, jsp, .class, .xml are there in the right place

3) deploy in a standalone Tomcat and check